# How can I create a related object in Django 2.0+, simply and effectively?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'd like to find a simple and robust way to create a child object. I think it is a simple problem, probably solved using Django RelationshipManager or Related objects reference.

I've gotten it to work in the past (by paying someone on fiver to help me solve this), but I feel that there is a much simpler method that escapes me.

This worked on my **views.py**

```py
class MainVisitForm(SingleObjectMixin, FormView):
    template_name = "clincher/visit_form.html"
    form_class = VisitForm
    model = Main

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()



        form=self.get_form()
        form.fk_visit_user = self.request.user
        form.fk_visit_main = Main.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        #added this to save form as we are mixxing the two forms and Models
        # as the approch of singleObjectMixin is we should get object from DB as per request url as a primary key
        #and we have defined  model as a Main but taking the form view of VistForm as the probem occures
        # as i think


        if form.is_valid():
            instance = Main()
            instance.firstname = form.cleaned_data['firstname']
            instance.middelname = form.cleaned_data['middlename']
            instance.lastname = form.cleaned_data['lastname']
            instance.date_of_birth = form.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
            instance.sex = form.cleaned_data['sex']

            instance.address = form.cleaned_data['address']
            instance.save()

        return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('clincher:main_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

Basically, while the user is in the details page of the "main" object, I would like them to be able to create a child object (visit object). Ultimately 1 patient will have many visits (1:m relationship). Each time a patient visits the doc, 1 new visit will be added, that is related to that person. Later, I will show a list of visits for that patient (but not the subject of this question).

**Models.py**

```py
class Main(models.Model):
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 256, verbose_name=('First Name'))
    middlename = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=('Middle Name'))
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=('Last Name'))
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    age = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    sex_list = (
        (str(1), 'Female'),
        (str(2), 'Male'),
        (str(3), 'Other'),
        (str(4), 'Unknown'),)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length = 24, choices=sex_list, verbose_name='Sex')
    address = models.TextField(max_length = 256)

    @property
    def full_name(self):
        #"Returns the person's full name."
        return '%s %s' % (self.firstname, self.lastname)

    #Redirects after form is submitted using primary key
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('clincher:main_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname +' - ' + str(self.date_of_birth)




class Visit(models.Model):
    fk_visit_main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=('Patient Name'))
    visit_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, editable=True)
    fk_visit_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=('Practitioner'), max_length=500)
    visit_label = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    visit_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        default=1, verbose_name='Type of Visit')
    visit_progress_notes = models.TextField(max_length=10000,
                                   blank=True, verbose_name='Progress Notes')
    outcomes = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.visit_date, self.visit_label)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('clincher:main_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

**forms.py**

```py
class VisitForm(forms.Form):
    visit_types_list = (
        (str(1), 'Consultation'),
        (str(2), 'Procedure'),
        (str(3), 'Administrative'),)
    visit_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=visit_types_list)
    visit_label = forms.CharField(label='Visit Label', max_length=100)
    progress_note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_visit_user = self.request.user
        form.instance.fk_visit_main = Main.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Thus, I should end up with a child record/object that has the primary key of the parent object.

The above code works, but I am sure that there is a simple Django-ey way of doing things much simpler, and in a robust manner. I think my solution should be found in the Django RelationshipManager, but I cannot find a solution that works. I paid a guy on Fiver, and I think he didn'y get this as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Check django InlineFormset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

If you want to have to abillity to add an remove the formset dynamically checkout (Jquery based) :
https://github.com/elo80ka/django-dynamic-formset

If you are using class based view you will have to add the inlineformset in `get_context_data()` and inside `form_valid()` check if the `formset.is_valid()` and then save it to the database.

EDIT: Here is the code based on your comment

forms.py

```
class VisitForm(forms.ModelForm);
    class Meta:
        model = Visit
        fields = [
            'visit_type',
            'visit_label',
            'visit_progress_notes'
        ]
```

views.py

```
class CreateVisitView(CreateView):
    model = Visit
    form_class = VisitForm
    template_name =  "clincher/visit_form.html"

    #one of the first function called in class based view, best place to manage conditional access
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        return super(CreateVisitView,self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        visit = form.save(commit=False)
        visit.fk_visit_user = self.request.username
        visit.fk_visit_main = get_object_or_404(Main, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        visit.save()

        return super(CreateVisitView,self).form_valid(form)
```

models.py

```
    class Main(models.Model):
        SEX_LIST_CHOICE = (
            (str(1), 'Female'),
            (str(2), 'Male'),
            (str(3), 'Other'),
            (str(4), 'Unknown'),
        )

        firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 256, verbose_name=('First Name'))
        middlename = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=('Middle Name'))
        lastname = models.CharField(max_length=256, verbose_name=('Last Name'))
        date_of_birth = models.DateField()

        age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

        sex = models.CharField(max_length = 24, choices=SEX_LIST_CHOICE, verbose_name='Sex')
        address = models.TextField(max_length = 256)

        @property
        def full_name(self):
            #"Returns the person's full name."
            return '%s %s' % (self.firstname, self.lastname)

        #Redirects after form is submitted using primary key
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('clincher:main_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

        def __str__(self):
            return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname +' - ' + str(self.date_of_birth)



class Visit(models.Model):
    VISIT_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        (str(1), 'Consultation'),
        (str(2), 'Procedure'),
        (str(3), 'Administrative'),)

    fk_visit_main = models.ForeignKey(Main, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name=('Patient Name'))
    visit_date = models.DateField(auto_now = True, editable=True)
    fk_visit_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name=('Practitioner'), max_length=500)
    visit_label = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    #you are storing the type of visit as an 
    visit_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=256,
        default=1,
        verbose_name='Type of Visit',
        choices=VISIT_TYPE_CHOICE
    )
    visit_progress_notes = models.TextField(max_length=10000,
                                   blank=True, verbose_name='Progress Notes')
    outcomes = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.visit_date, self.visit_label)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('clincher:main_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Comment: I think the InlineFormset will be very useful for some parts of this project. The issue is that I only need to add one child ("Visit") record each time. In fact, each visit will have a virtual essay written for it (textarea with tinymce editor on it). Can inline formsets be used this way? Where only one entry can be added? From my understanding, the inline formset is used when several child records are to be added or modified.

Comment: Yes, inlineformset is a little bit overkill then. But you rise a point, a Main can only have 1 Visit right? Maybe you don't need a ForeginKey to Main in visit but a `OneToOneField`?

Comment: Oh, no no, there will be many visits for each "Main" (which I have since changed to "Profile"). A person/profile will make several visits to the doctor.

Comment: Ok, so you try to create a view for entering the details about a Visit and pass the associated Main entry? Do you already have all informations about the Main instance already stored in the database?(it will be ok to just select the Main in a dropdown?)

Comment: So basically, the user in the Profile (Main) detail page, looking at name, dob and maybe a list of visits. The user clicks on new visits, and takes him to a form, that already has the foreign key populated, so that the user does not have to select the Main (Profile) from a dropdown. This would add to the list of visits in the Main (Profile) detail page.

Comment: Can you add your VisitForm in the question?

Comment: Just added it to the question

Answer (score 1):

So a number of things here that you could clear up.

1. `instance.middelname = form.cleaned_data['middlename']` Will never work as middlename is incorrect on the instance side.
2. You can use `Main.objects.create(firstname=form.validated_data['firstname'], lastname= .... etc)` to create your Model instances
3. You should probably have the relation from a User to your models be via Main, not Visit. This will allow you to add records for a Visit easier, for example, staff member logging visits instead of customer.
4. You should lookup CreateView to assist you with the boilerplate of creating an instance.
5. Rename the Main model. What is it actually? Looks like a Profile to me, but calling it Main isn't very descriptive.
6. Age should be an integer field. Nobody is 'dave' years old.

Comment: I think your right about the CreateView being the right choice. How do I go about getting the pk from the "main" (which I will rightly change to "Profile") model and putting it into the foreign key of the Visit model? What function within the CreateView class do I need to implement?